# Laravel model not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to create post page with comments; however, it's not working when I add the comment to a post because the system doesn't recognize the post id. What I'm I doing wrong that it doesn't know that the post_id is equal to $post_id

**I'm getting the following error:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'post_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (This is a test comment, 2017-08-15 19:51:47, 2017-08-15 19:51:47))

COMMENTS FORM

```
 <div class="well">
    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>

    <form role="form" method="post" action="{{ $post->id }}/comments">
    {{  csrf_field() }}

       <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
       </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

ROUTE

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@store');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function store(Post $post)
{
    $post->addComment(request('body'));

    return back();
}
```

COMMENT MODEL

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

POST MODEL

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function addComment($body)
    {
        Comment::create([
            'body' => $body,
            'post_id' => $this->id
        ]);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding post_id and body to fillable array in Post Model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`post_id` isn't in fillable array:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body', 'post_id']; //<---
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see, your controller function doen't know what post your talking about. You need to use the post id that is coming back from your form and locate the post then you can save the new comment like this

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

As shown in the [Laravel Docs 5.4 Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) it will fill the id in for you.

Also if I remember correctly you do not need to add ['post_id'] to your array of fillable fields.

The SQL error can be resolved by using a "column modifier". (see below)

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email')->nullable();
});
```

[Laravel Docs 5.4 Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#column-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

in your table in mysql make sure your post_id is auto increment or can be "null".  This error is saying post_id has no value and cant be default.

From the look of your code post_id is your primary key but not set to auto increment